# Customize Google authentication content screen

Tags: google-authentication

How to customize the google auth permissions screen.
I updated the content screen in google api console but its not reflecting in the content screen.

I tried to added the google plus page to api console but its not accepting it.
I found that there is a bug related to it. [Check this link](https://plus.google.com/+Olalaweb/posts/C31vsWsjKQe).

My content screen is appearing link this[image]

I Update api content screen as show below
[image]